# How to skip/dummy columns in mysqlsh importTable util?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, import-table

I want to explicit list the `columns` in `importTable` for `LOAD DATA` with `mysqlsh`:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-parallel-table.html

import.js:

```
util.importTable("sample.csv", {schema: "myschema", table: "mytable", 
    showProgress: true, columns: ["id","firstname",@dummy,@dummy,"lastname"]});
```

My csv contains 5 columns. But if my final table only contains `id, firstname, lastname`, I have to find a way to skip two columns of the source csv,

Import with:

```
mysqlsh --user=root --password='rootpw' --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock < import.js
```

Problem: `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at STDIN:2:347`. Neither `@dummy` nor `'@dummy'` nor `"@dummy"` works.

Question: how can I skip dummy columns? When using `LOAD DATA` it would work with using `@dummy` in the column options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Since MySQL Shell 8.0.22 you can skip columns by replacing column name in `columns` option with integer value.

```
util.importTable("/tmp/names.csv", {
    table:"names",
    columns: ["id", "firstname", 1, 2, "lastname"],
    dialect: "csv-unix"
});
```

which is equivalent to:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/names.csv' INTO TABLE `names`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(id, firstname, @1, @2, lastname);
```

## MySQL Shell >= 8.0.22

MySQL Shell’s parallel table import utility util.importTable() since version 8.0.22 has a new option `decodeColumns`, and an enhancement to the `columns` option, to enable you to
capture columns from the import file for input preprocessing (or to discard them) in the same way as with a `LOAD DATA` statement. The `decodeColumns` option
specifies preprocessing transformations for the captured data in the same way as the `SET` clause of a `LOAD DATA` statement, and assigns them to columns in the target table.

`util.importTable` `column` option was extended and now is accepting integers as array value. Integer value passed as `k`-th argument, captures `k`-th column
in input file as user variable named `@i`, where `i` is an passed integer.

Captured column value binded to user variable can be used in `decodeColumns`
option to preprocess and transform data before assigning the result to the
column in table.

Example 1 - Preprocess column2:

```
util.importTable('file.txt', {
  table: 't1',
  columns: ['column1', 1],
  decodeColumns: {'column2': '@1 / 100'}
});
```

is equivalent to:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt'
INTO TABLE `t1` (column1, @var1)
SET `column2` = @var/100;
```

Example 2 - Skip columns:

```
util.importTable('file.txt', {
  table: 't1',
  columns: ['column1', 1, 'column2', 2, 'column3']
});
```

is equivalent to:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt'
INTO TABLE `t1` (column1, @1, column2, @2, column3);
```

Example 3 - Generate values for columns

```
util.importTable('file.txt', {
  table: 't1',
  columns: [1, 2],
  decodeColumns: {
    'a': '@1',
    'b': '@2',
    'sum': '@1 + @2',
    'mul': '@1 * @2',
    'pow': 'POW(@1, @2)'
  }
});
```

is equivalent to:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt'
INTO TABLE `t1` (@1, @2)
SET
  `a` = @1,
  `b` = @2,
  `sum` = @1 + @2,
  `mul` = @1 * @2,
  `pow` = POW(@1, @2);
```

## 8.0.17 <= MySQL Shell < 8.0.22

Unfortunately, currently `util.importTable` in MySQL Shell 8.0.18 do not support user variables passed to columns options.

You can workaround this limitation by ALTER TABLE with missing columns that exists in import data file with proper column type:

```
alter table names add column (dummy1 integer, dummy2 integer);
```

import your data e.g. `/tmp/names.csv`[1]

```
util.importTable("/tmp/names.csv", {table:"names", columns: ["id", "firstname", "dummy1", "dummy2", "lastname"], dialect: "csv-unix"})
```

and drop `dummy` columns:

```
alter table names drop column dummy1;
alter table names drop column dummy2;
```

or simply invoke LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE SQL command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/sample.csv'
  INTO TABLE myschema.mytable
  (id, firstname, @dummy, @dummy, lastname);
```

[1] Sample data `/tmp/names.csv`

```
1,"Nicole",71,29,"Tusk"
2,"Bob",49,66,"Schiffer"
3,"Susan",61,17,"Tusk"
4,"Bob",24,59,"Trump"
5,"Nicole",25,46,"Goldberg"
6,"Bob",16,71,"Goldberg"
7,"Mark",43,43,"Schiffer"
```